# Blazor data-binding of input range doesn't seem to work properly with floating point step

Tags: html, data-binding, blazor

I have a slider, which the user should use to set a percentage threshold value.
The following code snipped works fine:

```
<span class="label label-default">Detection Threshold: @_objectDetectionThreshold %</span>
<input type="range" class="slider" min="0.0" step="1" max="100.0"
    @bind-value="_objectDetectionThreshold" @bind-value:event="oninput"
    data-toggle="tooltip" title=@_objectDetectionThreshold data-placement="top" />
```

`_objectDetectionThreshold` is simply a private field in the code:

```
private float _objectDetectionThreshold = 80.0f;
```

Changing the code above only by setting `step="0.1"`, or any float value will cause some issues, where the value only gets update very slowly and the slider will start to jump around while dragging.
What is the issue here and how can it be avoided?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Thanks for the suggestion, however using the `onchange` event doesn't solve the issue. Even if the value is updated for all small steps, this shouldn't be much in terms of sent data. My guess is, that it is some conversion problem, since all my values remain full numbers in all cases...

Comment: No, it is not related to conversion, but to re-rendering. And using a string type will not solve the issue, but create real issues.

Comment: @enet, I thought that too, but how do you explain that `_objectDetectionThreshold` is always rounded to the closest int value when changing values? I didn't get it.

Comment: I can't notice such behavior in my code sample. It is always increase `0.1` or descease `0.1` at each step. There is no issue related to conversion, and even if there was, the behvior described by the OP is due to the number of re-renderings that occur while dragging the slider.  Understand this: At each step your page is re-render.

Comment: I run this code which I copied from the question...try it: <span class="label label-default">Detection Threshold: @_objectDetectionThreshold %</span>
<input type="range" class="slider" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="100.0"
       @bind-value="_objectDetectionThreshold" @bind-value:event="oninput"
       data-toggle="tooltip" title=@_objectDetectionThreshold data-placement="top"/>

{replace with an at sign}code
{
    private float _objectDetectionThreshold = 80.0f;
}

Comment: @enet Yes this is the code I use. With keyboard: does not change the value. With cursor: only int values are displayed.

Comment: When you use a keyboard, say the right arrow left, you first have to select the dragger of the slider (I mean the circular part) with the mouse, and then press the right arrow left... As for the int values, I can't help you with this as we both use the same code

Comment: Yes I know how to do it and i can tell this is trying because if I keep pression on the key the circular part is twitching like it tries to go left but keeps being pushed back.

Comment: Can you provide an MRE? Here is your code on [blazor fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/clmlw5dx). Can you see the same issue? I changed your span to a div so they are on separate lines. The only jumping I see is when you have them on the same line and the number changes from single to double digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by `Jesse Good`, I've realized that the cause of the abberation is the display mode of the span element, which should be `block` and not `inline.` Thus you can either use:

```
<span style="display: block">Detection Threshold: @_objectDetectionThreshold %</span>
```

Or a div element, which is by default a block element

Now your miserable element can work well.

The issue is in the rendering domain, not conversion. The reason for the aberration is clear, the solution is clear, but some, perhaps lots of thought is required to get a complete picture why the rendering is distorted that way...

=======================This is my comment =====================

All the code snippets you provided prove my claim, and you do agree with me, not only with code but with words: `exactly as you described` But again, and this is the fourth time I'm telling you this: Run your code on **your own PC** with a span with `style="display: block"` omitted, but with `CultureInfo englishCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");`

...OK run this code and tell me if it works for you:

```
<span class="label label-default">
    Detection Threshold: @_objectDetectionThreshold %
</span>
<input type="range" class="slider my-2" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="100.0"
        @bind-value="_objectDetectionThreshold" @bind-value:event="oninput" @bind-value:culture="@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture"
        data-toggle="tooltip" title=@_objectDetectionThreshold data-placement="top" />
```

This code is `supposed` to work for you if the issue is one of conversion, as it configure:

```
@bind-value:culture="@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture"
```

Right? If it does not, it is because the code snippet is using inline span element.

Note: Not all dead old folks with Covid-19 dies from the disease, or their death is related to it. And not all code modifications introduced to software program are the correct solution, though their introduction result in the issues disappear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts!! Unfortunately, my issue still remains. Since the fiddle from @Jesse Good works for me as expected, I thought that there is some other hidden issue in my code. So I removed all the code in that page except for the code seen in the fiddle: issue still remains. Then I created a new blazor server project in .net6 (original project is .net5), without any other modifications and added the code from the fiddle: same issue again. As soon as I switch to `private string _objectDetectionThreshold = "80.0";` everything works normally. I'm confused....

Comment: Sidenote: completely removing `<div>Detection Threshold: @_objectDetectionThreshold %</div>` does not affect the problem at all. I also tried to remove any `css` class from the slider itself. Additionally, removing the tooltip also doesn't solve the problem..
Again, for me it's actually not a big issue, I can simply use a string as backing field, but the problem itself is quite curious.

Comment: @RolandDeschain , Here's the link to the issue I created in Github: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40894

Answer (score 4):

I finally got the correct answer:
The issue, was a simple culture info problem. My Windows installation is set to German, where the decimal divider is a `,` instead of a `.`.

Changing the code to

```
<input type="range" class="slider" min="0.0" step="0.1" max="100.0"
           @bind-value="_objectDetectionThreshold" @bind-value:event="oninput" @bind-value:culture=@englishCultureInfo
           data-toggle="tooltip" title=@_objectDetectionThreshold data-placement="top" />
@code{
    private float _objectDetectionThreshold = 80.0f;
    CultureInfo englishCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");

}
```

solves the problem.

Alternatively globalization could be handled globally in the project file ([see relevant docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#globalization)):

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

which solves the problem as well.

[@enet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152891/enet), since I'm sure your answer provides an important part to consider, could you add this info to your answer, so that we have one combined answer. I'll then mark it as the correct one.

Comment: `Changing the code to`...`solves the problem` Do you mean that you can now use the span element without `style="display: block"` Incidentally, I've configured my app to use German locale, but can discern no issue with the span element; that is whether I use German locale or US locale the behavior is the same.  But when I ommited `style="display: block"` in the span element, when I use either German locale or US locale the behavior of the input range element becomes erratic.

Comment: So again, do you use the span element at all, ommitting `style="display: block"`. It seems you do, as the code snippet in your answer does not use the span element, which is the source of the issue. I hope I'm clear. Remember, not all dead old folks with Covid-19 died from the virus.

Comment: @enet On my end it means the following: Running the code snipped in the [blazor fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/clmlw5dx) above provided by `Jesse Good` AS IS still produces the issue. Only if I change the culture info as described in my answer the issue is solved.

Comment: Sorry, you did not answer my question, which I repeated once again, and I'll ask it once more here: Do you use a span with `style="display: block"` omitted in your solution or not? And if you do not, then use it and tell me if it still works for you...

Comment: I provided a fiddle which hopefully makes it a bit clearer: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/8nvjikwy. 
To make things even more complicated: In my actual project it is as I described, which means that changing the culturinfo solves the issue. However, in the provided fiddle,  I can see the issue only in the cases where the `<span>` is not displayed as block (exactly as you described).  So I guess we are actually talking about two separate problems with the same resulting effect.

Comment: Please, see my response to your last comment at the end of my answer...

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer, but you post no response. I really want to understand what is going on here. Could you please tell me the result of the experiment I asked you to perform.

Comment: `fourth time I'm telling you this: Run your code on your own PC with a span...` - I have already done this several times. All the code snipppets in my last blazor fiddle where tested on my PC, with the result described in the headings of the fiddle. Sorry if I communicated badly.

Comment: OK.. thank you. I'm going to post this question in Github, as I've no idea why inline span interfere with the display of the range element.

Comment: Perfect! Yes, that would be interesting! Could you link your Github post to your answer, so that new readers will have the full picture? I marked your answer, as it now considers both problem sources :)